# Selectable optgroups in Select2

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I want to create multilevel select2 options with indentation but I don't want to use `optgroup` elements for this because I want to allow select also main categories. Is there any way to style if for select2?

My raw HTML select looks like this:

```
<select class="js-select-multiple">
  <option class="l1">Option 1</option>
  <option class="l2">Suboption 1</option>
  <option class="l2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option class="l2">Suboption 3</option>
  <option class="l1">Option 2</option>
  ...
</select>
<script>$(".js-select-multiple").select2({maximumSelectionLength: 5});</script>
```

So without using Select2 I can add `text-indent` property to `.l2` class. However it seems that `Select2` doesn't use those classes that are used for option, so styling those classes won't work.

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 36):

You're correct in recognizing that Select2 does not carry the CSS classes from the `<option>` tags to the results list. This mostly has to do with not explicitly tying the results list to existing `<option>` tags, and also having a set of sensible defaults. It's easier to add the ability to transfer classes afterwards than it is to remove them.

You can do this by overriding `templateResult` and getting the original option from `data.element` (where `data` is the first parameter).

```js
$('.select2').select2({
  templateResult: function (data) {    
    // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
    if (!data.element) {
      return data.text;
    }

    var $element = $(data.element);

    var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
    $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

    $wrapper.text(data.text);

    return $wrapper;
  }
});
```

```css
.l2 {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2" style="width: 200px">
  <option class="l1">Option 1</option>
  <option class="l2">Suboption 1</option>
  <option class="l2">Suboption 2</option>
  <option class="l2">Suboption 3</option>
  <option class="l1">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Note that I am also using `padding-left` instead of `text-indent`, which is what Select2 usually uses for nested options.

Comment: The search box wouldn't work very well using this method. E.g. if you add Suboption 4 under option 2 and searched for `sub` you won't know which category the suboptions belong to since level 1 categories would be excluded from the results.