# Select2 - Can’t select values from a multi-level tree

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a multi-level Select2, divided in groups, subgroups and options. The expected behavior is that only options can be selected. For an unkonwn reason, only the first level childs can be selected (meaning values Option 1.1 and Option 1.2 in the code below):

```
$(function() {
  var theData = [{
      "id": "",
      "text": ""
    },
    {
      "text": "Group 1",
      "children": [{
          "id": 1,
          "text": "Option 1.1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "Option 1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Group 2",
      "children": [{
          "id": 3,
          "text": "Subgroup 2.1",
          "children": [{
              "id": 41,
              "text": "Option 2.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": 42,
              "text": "Option 2.1.2"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  $("#mySelect").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a option...",
    data: theData
  });
});
```

The HTML goes just like this

```
<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" style="width:400px;"></select>
```

I've made a fiddle to better demostrate this https://jsfiddle.net/zjy16uo9/. There you can see that only those two values can be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit a limitation of HTML version 5 and below. `<optgroup>`s are not nestable, [their only allowed parent is `<select>`](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/optgroup.html#optgroup-context).

[Select2 docs warn against it](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats):

> Because Select2 generates an `<optgroup>` when creating nested options, only a single level of nesting is supported. Any additional levels of nesting is not guaranteed to be displayed properly across all browsers and devices.

[Furthermore](https://select2.org/options#hierarchical-options):

> ## Hierarchical options
>
> Only a single level of nesting is allowed per the HTML specification.
>   If you nest an `<optgroup>` within another `<optgroup>,` Select2 will
>   not be able to detect the extra level of nesting and errors may be
>   triggered as a result.
>
> Furthermore, `<optgroup>` elements **cannot** be made selectable.
>   **This is a limitation of the HTML specification** and is not a limitation that Select2 can overcome.
>
> If you wish to create a true hierarchy of selectable options, use an
>   `<option>` instead of an `<optgroup>` and [change the style with
>   CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30820215/359284#30948247). Please note that this approach may be considered "less
>   accessible" as it relies on CSS styling, rather than the semantic
>   meaning of `<optgroup>`, to generate the effect.

## In practice/Demo

Select2, as said, renders a `<select>`. From your fiddle, you can get the one it renders by inspecting the DOM.

I copied the rendered DOM and pasted in the demo below.

**Look how the nested `<optgroup>`s aren't really nested**, no matter the level, they are rendered only one level deep.

```js
$(function() {
  var theData = [{
      "id": "",
      "text": ""
    },
    {
      "text": "Group 1",
      "children": [{
          "id": 1,
          "text": "Option 1.1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "Option 1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Group 2",
      "children": [{
          "id": 3,
          "text": "Subgroup 2.1",
          "children": [{
              "id": 41,
              "text": "Option 2.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": 42,
              "text": "Option 2.1.2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "text": "Subgroup 2.2",
          "children": [{
              "id": 41,
              "text": "Subgroup 2.2.1",
              "children": [{
                "id": 41,
                "text": "Option 2.2.1.1"
              }]
            },
            {
              "id": 42,
              "text": "Subgroup 2.2.2",
              "children": [{
                  "id": 41,
                  "text": "Option 2.2.2.1"
                },
                {
                  "id": 42,
                  "text": "Option 2.2.2.2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  $("#mySelect").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a option...",
    data: theData
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css">

<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" style="width:400px;"></select>

<br>
<hr>
<br>
Notice how these nested optgroups are rendered as if they weren't nested at all. They are all only one level deep:<br>
<select>
    <option value="" data-select2-id="1"></option>
    <optgroup label="Group 1" data-select2-id="2">
        <option value="1" data-select2-id="3">Option 1.1</option>
        <option value="2" data-select2-id="4">Option 1.2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2" data-select2-id="5">
        <optgroup label="Subgroup 2.1" data-select2-id="6">
            <option value="41" data-select2-id="7">Option 2.1.1</option>
            <option value="42" data-select2-id="8">Option 2.1.2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Subgroup 2.2" data-select2-id="9">
            <optgroup label="Subgroup 2.2.1" data-select2-id="10">
                <option value="41" data-select2-id="11">Option 2.2.1.1</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Subgroup 2.2.2" data-select2-id="12">
                <option value="41" data-select2-id="13">Option 2.2.2.1</option>
                <option value="42" data-select2-id="14">Option 2.2.2.2</option>
            </optgroup>
        </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

## Workaround

I would follow the one [suggested by Select2](https://select2.org/options#hierarchical-options):

> If you wish to create a true hierarchy of selectable options, use an
>   `<option>` instead of an `<optgroup>` and [change the style with
>   CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30820215/359284#30948247). Please note that this approach may be considered "less
>   accessible" as it relies on CSS styling, rather than the semantic
>   meaning of `<optgroup>`, to generate the effect.

Comment: Those optgroups look nested to me.... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tim in the HTML they are nested, but in the rendered combobox they aren't. Run the demo and you'll see.