# nested dropped down filters with yadcf select2 and dataTables

Tags: datatables, jquery-select2, yadcf

I have been using dataTables+yacdf+select2 combination successfully for quite a while. Now I am working on converting my select2 to be an ordered indented drop-down list with optgroup selectable as well (https://select2.org/options, "Hierarchical options", [Selectable optgroups in Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820215/selectable-optgroups-in-select2#30948247)).

However with yacdf I can not seem to pass data to select2 in the hierarchical format like the one below:

```
var data = [

{ 
  "text": "Group 1", 
  "children" : [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "Option 1.1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "Option 1.2"
    }
  ]
},
{ 
  "text": "Group 2", 
  "children" : [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "Option 2.1"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "text": "Option 2.2"
    }
  ]
}];
```

Previously the working code was:

```
.yadcf([{column_number: 1, filter_type: "multi_select", select_type: 'select2', filter_container_id: "someFilter2", filter_default_label: "Select xxx", filter_reset_button_text: false, style_class: "form-control", 
        select_type_options: {
            multiple: 'multiple',
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: 'something',
            },

        data: [<comma separated list of values>]
```

yacdf source code states that:

```
    Required:           false
    Type:               Array (of string or objects)
    Description:        When the need of predefined data for filter is needed just use an array of strings ["value1","value2"....] (supported in select / multi_select / auto_complete filters) or array of objects [{value: 'Some Data 1', label: 'One'}, {value: 'Some Data 3', label: 'Three'}] (supported in select / multi_select filters)
```

Note:               that when filter_type is custom_func / multi_select_custom_func this array will populate the custom filter select element
"

Is it really not possible?
If not anybody managed to get nested dropped down filters work with dataTables any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `data_as_is: true` , [read docs for more info](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/630ee39247140e8d351e0ac5523ee0faf7a1cff6/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L54)

> - data_as_is
>                 Required:           false
>                 Type:               boolean
>                 Default value:      false
>                 Description:        When set to true, the value of the data attribute will be fed into the filter as is (without any modification/decoration).
>                                     Perfect to use when you want to define your own  for the filter
>                 Note:               Currently supported by the select / multi_select filters

Comment: Daniel thank you for looking into it. I did try to use data_as_is: False before posting a question. Unfortunately when I feed data in select2 array format (below) via yadcf with data_as_is: False, select2 does not seem to see it at all. When I feed it directly to the select2 element bypassing yadcf, it shows up.  var data = [
    
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    }   
];

Comment: Figured it out by looking into the yadcf source code. Need to feed data to select2 via yadcf in the following format: data: [ "<option value=\"option A\">option A</option>"]

Comment: @StanK "Perfect to use when you want to define your own <option></option> for the filter"