# Customise HTML select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make a select with grouped options, but this groups should be selectable too.

The standard select OPTGROUP option not selectable. I tried to use select2 or chosen plugin. It's possible to select the group here, but om select group all options in group selected and it looks like a multi-select (solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964909/selectable-optgroup-using-select2) ).
But I need to select optgroup (without multiselect) and handle it on server-side.

My intention is to customize group-items separately and display them as optgroup but keep behavior as option. Is it possible to customize select option separately?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my solution I combined [choosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and classic select object styling. I added css class "category" category items, and "item" for terminal items.

Standard select control showed bolded categories (it can't indent items) for me
[image]

But after choosen plugin initialized I got beauty select plugin with indentions like this

[image]