# Select2 group select. Values Automatically goes to the top when mouse is over values

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have a problem with Select2 optgroup select from 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964909/selectable-optgroup-using-select2). Of course before I write this I commented earlier in that topic but i dont have any answers.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="fruitSelect" value="" style="width:300px;" /><br />
<br />
<button type="button" id="showValue">Show Value</button><br />
<br />
<div id="output">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var FRUIT_GROUPS = [
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Citrus',
        children: [
            { id: 'c1', text: 'Grapefruit' },
            { id: 'c2', text: 'Orange' },
            { id: 'c3', text: 'Lemon' },
            { id: 'c4', text: 'Lime' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Other',
        children: [
            { id: 'o1', text: 'Apple' },
            { id: 'o2', text: 'Mango' },
            { id: 'o3', text: 'Banana' }
        ]
    }
    ,
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Other',
        children: [
            { id: 'o1', text: 'Apple' },
            { id: 'o2', text: 'Mango' },
            { id: 'o3', text: 'Banana' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Other2',
        children: [
            { id: 'o1', text: 'Apple2' },
            { id: 'o2', text: 'Mango2' },
            { id: 'o3', text: 'Banana2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Other3',
        children: [
            { id: 'o1', text: 'Apple3' },
            { id: 'o2', text: 'Mango3' },
            { id: 'o3', text: 'Banana3' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'Other4',
        children: [
            { id: 'o1', text: 'Apple4' },
            { id: 'o2', text: 'Mango4' },
            { id: 'o3', text: 'Banana4' }
        ]
    }

];

$('#fruitSelect').select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Select fruits...",
    data: FRUIT_GROUPS,
    query: function(options) {
        var selectedIds = options.element.select2('val');
        var selectableGroups = $.map(this.data, function(group) {
            var areChildrenAllSelected = true;
            $.each(group.children, function(i, child) {
                if (selectedIds.indexOf(child.id) < 0) {
                    areChildrenAllSelected = false;
                    return false; // Short-circuit $.each()
                }
           });
            return !areChildrenAllSelected ? group : null;
        });
        options.callback({ results: selectableGroups });
    }
}).on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    var $select = $(this);
    if (e.val == '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $select.select2('data', $select.select2('data').concat(e.choice.children));
        $select.select2('close');
    }
});

$('#showValue').click(function() {
    $('#output').text($('#fruitSelect').val());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ouxc9kbg/)

I have a problem with this code. When I choose for example "Mango3" then scrolling to the bottom of list just moving the mouse at the area of select then the scrolls goes automatically to the up. There is any fix of that?

Comment: It is a known issue of select2 before the V4: [Issue on github](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1672). Is it possible for you to update your select2 version to 4.x.x ?

Comment: @GilleQ.thank you, I am trying to update my select2. My current version is 3.5.4. Maybe it is a reason

Comment: There is this guide from Select2 to [migrate from 3.5 to v4](https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35) if that can help. I hope that it will help