# Group multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I try to make selection with [jQuery Select2](https://select2.org/selections) and use 'option' instead 'optgroup' to make it avaliable to choose.

Is there any way to auto-select all group when I choose 'FIRST'?

```
<select id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple>
           <option>FIRST</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
           <option>SECOND</option>
            <option value="6">Option 6</option>
            <option value="7">Option 7</option>
            <option value="8">Option 8</option>
            <option value="9">Option 9</option>
            <option value="10">Option 10</option>
 </select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Asunaro/gs0cj7mr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions for selectable groups.
First based on **select2.optgroupSelect.js** and here an example

```js
 $('#target').select2();
  $(function(){
     $.fn.select2.amd.require(["optgroup-data", "optgroup-results"], 
         function (OptgroupData, OptgroupResults) {
         $('#target').select2({
             dataAdapter: OptgroupData,
             resultsAdapter: OptgroupResults,
             closeOnSelect: false,
    
         }); 
     });
 });
```

```css
select {width:300px;}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/bnjmnhndrsn/select2-optgroup-select/master/example/vendor/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/bnjmnhndrsn/select2-optgroup-select/master/example/vendor/select2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/bnjmnhndrsn/select2-optgroup-select/master/dist/select2.optgroupSelect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css"  />
<select id="target" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple='multiple'>
     <optgroup label="FIRST">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option  value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option  value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option  value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="SECOND">
            <option class="456" value="6">Option 6</option>
            <option class="456" value="7">Option 7</option>
            <option class="456" value="8">Option 8</option>
            <option class="456" value="9">Option 9</option>
            <option class="456" value="10">Option 10</option>
       </optgroup>
 </select>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asunaro/gs0cj7mr/)

And the second way I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964909/selectable-optgroup-using-select2/27010142#27010142) , it based on hidden 'input' field

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56be9zop/58/)
[jsfiddle without query](http://jsfiddle.net/56be9zop/58/)

Answer (score -1):

add this in your html `<optgroup label="select all">`

as for Javascript:
https://jsfiddle.net/fchzd93s/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function RunSelect2(){
      $('#multipleSelectExample').select2({
         allowClear: true,
         closeOnSelect: false,
      }).on('select2:open', function() {  

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".select2-results__option .select2-results__group").bind( "click", selectAlllickHandler ); 
        }, 0);

      });
    }

    RunSelect2();

    var selectAlllickHandler = function() {
        $(".select2-results__option .select2-results__group").unbind( "click", selectAlllickHandler );        
      $('#multipleSelectExample').select2('destroy').find('option').prop('selected', 'selected').end();
      RunSelect2();
    };
    });
```

Comment: But how it works with several groups when I try to select options inside one of them?

Comment: You want to select all options of each group?

Comment: Yes, if it possible. Could you help me, please? Maybe I should use the same id for all options inside group?